# How to EXEC a query generated in a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE in which a `SELECT` statement is generated, but SQL Server (2012) does not allow calling `EXEC` on it. Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @guidToFind uniqueidentifier = 'E4069560-091A-4026-B519-104F1C7693B3';

WITH GuidCols (TableName, ColName, Query) As
(
    SELECT  
        C.TABLE_NAME, 
        C.COLUMN_NAME, 
        'SELECT ' + 
             QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + '.' + 
             QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' 
        FROM ' + 
             QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + ' 
        WHERE ' + 
           QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ''' + cast(@guidToFind AS VARCHAR(50))+
           ''''
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
        ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND 
           T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    WHERE 
        C.DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
)
-- SELECT * FROM
EXEC( GuidCols.Query )
```

The problem is not solve if I uncomment the `SELECT` statement after CTE.

The purpose of this query is to find all instances of a GUID in a database. Currently I'm solving this problem using a script like [this](https://gist.github.com/3180402). However I would be happier to solve this problem without iterating through rows, using set operations and other techniques.

Comment: `EXISTS` might be more efficient way to find instances of the GUID if you only wanto to know the tables and columns that contain the value.  You could assemble a single query that `UNION`s all of the results and then `EXECUTE` that string.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the tip. Can you please explain where can I use `EXISTS`? And in the second part you mean to make a string of hard-coded table and col names as in e.g., `'SELECT ''[table1]'', ''[Col5]'' UNION ALL SELECT ''[table3]'', ''[Col8]'''`?

Comment: @HABO I'm currently achieving this in this way: https://gist.github.com/3180402 
But I would be happier if I could use set operations instead of loop

Comment: In your github example you've added `DISTINCT` so that you only get one row if the GUID is found one or more times in a given table and column.  `select C.Table_Name, C.Column_Name from C.Table_Name where exists ( select 42 from C.Table_Name where C.Column_Name = @GuidToFind )` will return the table and column names if the column contains an instance of the GUID.  It makes it clear to the optimizer that you don't care how often the value is found, just that it is present.  If you `UNION` together a series of these queries for each table and column you'll have a list of where the GUID is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `exec` as a part of a `CTE`.

From [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

What you can do instead is to store the result from your query in a temp table, loop over the rows and execute one statement at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The EXEC() function is available from T-SQL, but it is not accessible from within a SQL statement.  I would assume this is the case because SQL is executed in several steps... something like:

1. Your statement is parsed.
2. An execution plan is generated.
3. The execution plan is run against the database and results are returned.

The EXEC() function is designed to dynamically execute a statement, so in order to do what you're asking, SQL Server would have to perform the first two steps, then while executing the statement, it would have to return back to the first step to parse/execute the dynamic statement.  This would have to be repeated for each row in your results.

I assume this type of 'feature' is not available because it could adversely affect the performance and complexity of the db engine; so they leave it to us to execute the first statement, then loop through each record to execute the dynamic statements individually.

Answer (score 1):

Exec executes a T-SQL command that you embed in its parentheses. The difference is that the EXEC() function can execute a string or string variable, as you saw in the preceiding code. The argument for EXEC() can be a literal string, but the real power of EXEC() comes to light when you use a variable.

It executes the command contained in the variable, but in a different context from the session calling the function. That's important, because it introduces some severe constraints. Any tables you create are visible to the EXEC() context, but variables declared by the calling session aren't visible to the EXEC() context, and vice versa.

I found an interesting article related to this at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921(v=sql.80).aspx

Although above is self sufficient, you can also go through  : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/13/sql-server-difference-between-exec-and-execute-vs-exec-use-execexecute-for-sp-always/

Answer (score 1):

You may use OPENQUERY instead of EXEC:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM joe.titles WHERE name = ''NewTitle''');
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017